# Problems deploying to github pages with vue project

Tags: git, github, vue.js, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy a vue-cli project to github pages, I followed the instructions on this website and on github support.

delpoy vue-cli to github pages:
https://medium.com/@mwolfhoffman/deploying-to-github-pages-with-vue-webpack-cli-5b2ba17f14a0

Configuring github pages
https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/

> Setting -> source -> master /docs
>
> have a /docs folder in the root of the repository
>
> not follow the repository naming scheme username.github.io or orgname.github.io

Here is my repository : https://github.com/leewei05/blog

But the result keep giving me 404, still doesn't know what my problem is, please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out I've got the wrong config path, here are the steps to deploy a new vue-cli project to git hub pages.

(You got to install npm and vue-cli first)

1. `$ vue init webpack [projectName]`
2. `$ cd [projectName]`
3. `$ npm install`
4. go to your config/index.js file
5. modify your build section like this:

```js
build: {
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../docs/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../docs'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '',
    productionSourceMap: true,
    devtool: '#source-map',
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  }
```

6. `$ npm run build`
7. push it to your github repository
8. go to the setting in your repository
9. find your GitHub Pages Section and change the source from
   'master' -> 'master/docs'
10. your page should be on `https://[userName].github.io/[repositoryName]/#/`
11. Good luck on that!

Comment: Hey I can't seem to change the source in Step 9. you mentioned above?

Comment: @AkinHwan you need to have full admin access for the repo and then you should be able to find the setting under 'Settings' > 'Options tab' > Github Pages section > Change the 'source' from 'master branch' to 'master branch /docs folder'.

Comment: @Evolve yes I am indeed admin for akinhwan.github.io  looks like when I visit akinhwan.github.io/docs/index.html I can see my site. I think I need to create a new branch?

Comment: @Lee What if you can't see the dropdown in Sources section of Options?

Comment: In case you want to automate this, I posted a solution to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56638750/6178576 - It uses the gh-pages branch instead of docs folder though.